# Disallow recursion on named.conf

Tags: domain-name-system, linux, named-conf

I want to disable recursive DNS queries against the nameserver

**Does this line work out**

recursion no;

**or do I have put in these lines**

allow-transfer {“none”;};
allow-recursion {“none”;};
recursion no;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`allow-transfer` has nothing to do with recursion - zone transfers are their own animal and have nothing to do with recursive lookups; they should only ever be allowed to slave authoritative servers.

Setting `recursion no;` means that all `allow-recursion` settings are irrelevant and will be ignored; that setting is indeed unnecessary.